# Subclasses in Django databases

Tags: python, django

If I have

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    widgets = models.ForeignKey('widgets.Widget', related_name='widgets')
```

I want to save a subclass, XWidget of Widget to the database. Is this ok, even though Foo.widgets is of the Widget parent class not XWidget?

When reading Foo.widgets, if I want to find all XWidgets is a filter a good way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may save a subclass to a foreign key referencing its parent, because `XWidget` *is-a* `Widget`. It won't work in reverse, though. For instance, if your foreign key was to 'widgets.XWidget', you couldn't save a `Widget` to it.

Comment: Thanks heaps! Seemed sensible, just wanted to make sure.
Is .filter a good way to sort an array to find a particular sub-class?